# Angular Attribute Selector: Output Binding Not Working

Tags: angular

I have 2 components: a list and a row.

In the list component's template, I use a table and to make the row work with the ngFor, I had to use an attribute selector for the child component (i.e. using square brackets):

```
@Component({
  selector: '[my-tr]'
.
.
})
```

The child component also has an output that's declared, initialized and then fired when a button is pressed:

```
@Output() onItemDeleted: EventEmitter<SubscriberListItem>; 
..
this.onItemDeleted = new EventEmitter<SubscriberListItem>();
..
this.onItemDeleted.emit(this.item);
```

Then on the parent component, the template includes the child as a table row as follows:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr my-tr *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item" (onItemDeleted)="removeItem($event)"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And here's the row's template:

```
<td width="25%">{{item.name}}</td>
<td width="40%">{{item.street}}</td>
<td width="5%">{{item.postCode}}</td>
<td width="30%">
    <button (click)="removeItem($event)">DELETE</button>        
</td>
```

**Here's the problem**: when the delete button is pressed on a row, the handler on the row component is called:

```
removeItem(event: any): void { 
   this.onItemDeleted.emit(this.item); 
}
```

This is good. However, when trying to fire the emitter, it never reaches the parent. Looking in the browser console, I'm seeing the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: co.removeItem is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SubscribersListComponent.html:191)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11799)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13007)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:12595)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8773)
    at core.es5.js:10638
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.es5.js:3840)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:236)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
    at EventEmitter.emit (core.es5.js:3814)
    at SubscriberRowComponent.webpackJsonp.537.SubscriberRowComponent.removeItem (subscriber-row.component.ts:35)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SubscriberRowComponent.html:7)
```

This is something to do with the fact that I'm using attribute selector on the table row for the child component. The context of the output binding on the row is not the parent component, therefore it is not finding the 'removeItem' function.

Can anyone help me solve this or suggest a fix?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you correctly but here is a simplified example that works:

```
  @Component({
  selector: '[my-tr]',
  template: '{{item}} <button (click)="removeItem($event)">DELETE</button>'
})
export class MyTr {
  @Input() item: any;
  @Output() onItemDeleted = new EventEmitter<any>; 

  removeItem(event: any): void { 
   this.onItemDeleted.emit(this.item); 
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div my-tr *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item" (onItemDeleted)="removeItem($event)"></div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  removeItem(item) {
    console.log('removeItem', item);
  }
}
```